# Visual Studio add reference automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I use some basic namespaces on each project so it can be boring when I always do as `Project-->Add reference`. Is there any easier way?

Comment: Create your own project template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project templates are the way to go - see [Creating Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx) in MSDN for details.

Answer (score 0):

Project is just an xml page, you can modify it from notepad. Just add the needed references to one of your project and then copy-paste them to others.